# Requires: python(abi) = 3.6 on Centos 7 when installing iRedMail

Tags: python-3.x, centos, centos7, iredmail

Hello to all the community.

I am currently installing an email system on our online cloud server using the iRedMail solution.

I followed the official procedure via the ./iRedMail.sh file. The problem is that some packages require a dollar which it cannot find. Python verion 3.6 (abi) it seems.

Here is the error message:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution  Error: Package: python36-sqlalchemy-1.1.3-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: python(abi) = 3.6
       Installed: python-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64 (installed)
```

Details about my centos distribution :

[image: My Centos Distributions settings]

I think we should install python (abi) 3.6 but I am wondering the correct procedure to point the installation to the new python (3.6) library for installation.

Thank you to all of you...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The capability `python(abi) = 3.6` is provided by `python3` package from the base CentOS 7 repository.

In all likelihood, you have disabled it.

The following should work:

```
yum install python3
```

If it cannot locate package, investigate repo configurations under `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and enable the base repo.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me.

I tried the yum install python3 command but to no avail. It was also necessary to add the ius-repo in the repositories.

But there are always two bothering bookstores.

I don't know if it's due to x86_64 on the package. Otherwise I tried to downgrade with the command:

yum downgrade systemd-libs libgudev1 systemd systemd-sysv

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is the error :                                                                                                       
       Error: Package: systemd-python-219-42.el7_4.10.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
           Requires: systemd = 219-42.el7_4.10
           Installed: systemd-219-57.el7.x86_64 (installed)                                                               Error: Package: systemd-python-219-42.el7_4.10.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
           Requires: systemd-libs = 219-42.el7_4.10
           Installed: systemd-libs-219-57.el7.x86_64 (installed)

Comment: This is the last error it shows afeter try to downgrade                                               
           Error: Package: systemd-219-42.el7_4.10.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
           Requires: redhat-release >= 7.0